# How to automatically install removed network printers?

Tags: windows, networking, drivers, installation, printer

By default Windows installs network printers automatically with an IPP or another type of basic print driver.

I discovered that when you delete such an automatically installed printer it won't be installed a second time automatically. I think this is default behaviour of Windows so deleted printers won't automatically install again and someone could never get rid of his printer. A lot of examples regarding this situation can be found online. So far so good.

Of course I can install the printer again manually by clicking the search for printers button in the printers and scanners window.

My question is: Is there a possibility to let Windows again automatically install the printer? Looks like somewhere the OS stores a list of devices (e.g. printers) which were previously installed automatically and therefore won't install anymore, except manually.

Maybe it is in the registry or somewhere else?

I tried already to put the turn on automatic setup of network connected devices. Checkmark off and one in the advanced sharing settings section of the network and sharing center. Did not do anything.

*Question is asked purely out of curiosity. As said: I can install the printer manually.*